# Declaring dynamic call of BAdi?

Tags: dynamic, declaration, abap, badi

I want to define an object for BAdI implementation that will not initialize the BAdI by its name in declaration.

**Example** of what I don't want:

```
DATA l_split_badi TYPE REF TO fieb_get_bank_stmts_x.
```

**Question 1 :** I want **something like**:

```
DATA l_split_badi TYPE REF TO object.
lv_class_name = 'fieb_get_bank_stmts_x'.
create object l_split_badi type (lv_class_name).
```

If I declare like above, I get the following syntax error:

> "L_SPLIT_BADI" is not a valid BAdI handle here.

**The reason why I need to perform such implementation is**, while importing the Change request to a system which has an older SAP version, the import fails because of BAdI declaration with `TYPE REF TO` (because that BAdI doesn't exist in the system).

My idea is with dynamic declaration to avoid the pre-check on importing the Change request.

Any idea is welcome !
Thanks to all !

---

**EDIT Question 2** : after solution proposed by Sandra Rossi to use `DATA l_split_badi TYPE REF TO cl_badi_base` and `GET BADI l_split_badi TYPE ('FIEB_GET_BANK_STMTS_X')`, I get the same syntax error at line `CALL BADI l_split_badi->split` below:

```
CALL BADI l_split_badi->split
  EXPORTING
    i_string           = lv_cont
  IMPORTING
    et_string          = lt_xml_string
  EXCEPTIONS
    split_not_possible = 1
    wrong_format       = 2.
```

Comment: I moved the complementary question as a distinct EDIT so that to not put the initial solution proposed out of context. Please edit or let's discuss if you don't agree.

Answer (score 3):

#### Question 1

For BAdIs which are part of an Enhancement Spot (display the BAdI via the transaction code `SE18` and you will know), you must not use `CREATE OBJECT`, but instead [**GET BADI**](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapget_badi.htm) which has a dynamic variant:

```
DATA badi TYPE REF TO cl_badi_base.
TRY.
    GET BADI badi TYPE ('FIEB_GET_BANK_STMTS_X')...
  CATCH cx_badi_unknown_error INTO DATA(lx).
    " The BAdI doesn't exist, handle the case...
ENDTRY.
```

EDIT: notice that the instance declaration is referencing `CL_BADI_BASE`, the super class of all BAdI definitions.

#### Question 2

Calling the method `SPLIT` statically is invalid because `SPLIT` doesn't exist in `CL_BADI_BASE`. You must use the dynamic variant of [**CALL BADI**](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_badi.htm):

```
CALL BADI l_split_badi->('SPLIT')
  EXPORTING
    i_string           = lv_cont
  IMPORTING
    et_string          = lt_xml_string
  EXCEPTIONS
    split_not_possible = 1
    wrong_format       = 2.
```

Comment: Hi Sandra. Thanks for you answer and explanation. I extended only FILTERS part to filter for FORMAT_GROUP_X.  At the end i'm still seeing that annoying error while activating saying that  "l_split_badi is not a valid BAdI handle here.", I've checked in debugger both badi elements ( fixed defined/dynamic defined ) look totally same. They have main badi class, badi definition, interface and so on... I can't understand what is sitll wrong.

Comment: Did you reference `cl_badi_base` instead of `object`? If yes, please edit your question and paste the reproducible code in an "EDIT" section.

Comment: Dear Sandra. I have updated all my declarations in the initial issue described above. Any ideas are welcomed! :)

Comment: Please don't change your original question such as making the answers incoherent. Just add it in a new "EDIT" section at the bottom of the question. Moreover, could you clarify which line has the syntax error? NB: calling the method PARSE statically is invalid because PARSE doesn't exist in `CL_BADI_BASE`, you must call it dynamically (`CALL BADI l_split_badi->('PARSE') ...`)

Comment: Many thanks Sandra! It works now! :) As you said in prevous comment we can't access them directly because they are not defined in the super class (CL_BADI_BASE). In suggested way they are accessed based on BADI type and thus functional. No further issues :)

Comment: For information, I have completed my answer so that to help future visitors, and edited the question to make the question and answer coherent.